# ¿Como simular un join en Firebase entre dos documentos en Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, join

Tengo dos documentos en firebase, uno es usuarios y el otro son publicaciones, entonces en el documento de usuarios están todos los datos de un usuario y en publicaciones sus datos pero con el uid de quien lo publicó, pero no se como simular un join entre dos documentos, ya que quiero hacer un apartado donde se muestren todas las publicaciones y quien las publicó pero no se como hacer para que a partir del uid de publicaciones poder traerme la información de usuarios tal como nombre, correo etc.

Adjunto imagenes
[image: Documento publicaciones]

[image: Documento usuarios]

Aqui es donde no me imagino como realizarlo
[image: Ejemplo de como quisiera hacer el servicio]

Y esto es como quisiera que se mostrara, la información de la publicación y el nombre de usuario
[image: Como quisiera que fuera al final]

edit

Realicé esto pero no se si es correcto

```
getCurrentUser(uid:string){
return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges();}

obtenerTodasPublicaciones(){
let mapita = new Map();
return this.afs.collection('publicacion').get()
.subscribe((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
    this.getCurrentUser(doc.data().uid)
    .subscribe(response => {
      mapita.set(doc.data(),response);
    });

  });
  console.log(mapita);
});
```

}

funciona pero no se si haya alguna forma correcta de hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes usar los query filter que te provee firebase, en este caso seria algo asi como:

```
getPublicaciones(user) {
return this.afs.collection('publicacion', ref => ref.where('uid','==', 
 user.uid)).valueChanges()
}
```

Con esto consigues que firebase te traiga las publicaciones de un usuario concreto atraves de su uid.

Aqui te dejo la documentación de firebase sobre los query filters:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó, de pura casualidad no sabes como traer todas las publicaciones de todos los usuarios existentes? Ese es para un usuario en concreto pero me gustaría obtener todas las publicaciones de todos los usuarios y a la par la información de estos mismos usuarios

Comment: Claro pero el tratamiento de los datos deberá ser diferente, quiero decir que tendrás que traer todas la publicaciones a un array y luego recorrerlo haciendo una petición a firebase por cada publicación para que te traiga la info del usuario de dicha publicación.